# Fragments Communication including FragmentDrawer and FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, communication, fragmentpageradapter, drawer

I spent the last days searching for a way to communicate two fragments, there are tons of answers and tutorials about how to do it but none of them worked for me. I tried parcelable, boundle, interfaces but nothing worked (probably because I made a mistake implementing them).

The tricky thing is that most tutorials explain a basic case with two fragments with IDs in their layouts but my app has a more complex architecture. Check the image below:

[image: App Architecture]

The aim is to send a custom object from the ListView (lv1) to ListView (lv2). Each listview is in a fragment created using FragmentPagerAdapter and belong to a different Drawer Fragment as explained in the image.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

MainActivity code of how Navigation Drawer fragments are created:

```
@Override
public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
    displayView(position);
}
private void displayView(int position) {
    String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
    HomeFragment homeFragment = null;
    QuotesFragment quotesFragment = null;
    WatchlistFragment watchlistFragment = null;

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_inicio);
            break;
        case 1:
            quotesFragment = new QuotesFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_cotizaciones);
            break;
        case 2:
            watchlistFragment = new WatchlistFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_messages);
            break;
    }

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, homeFragment, "HomeFragment");
            break;
        case 1:
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, quotesFragment, "QuotesFragment");
            break;
        case 2:
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, watchlistFragment, "WatchlistFragment");
            break;
    }
```

Also, check below the code of how fragmentpageadapter creates the fragmenttabs:

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new QuotesIndexespage(),getResources().getString(R.string.one));
    adapter.addFragment(new QuotesCurrenciesPage(),getResources().getString(R.string.two));
    adapter.addFragment(new QuotesCommoditiesPage(),getResources().getString(R.string.three));
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}



class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try [eventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

Comment: @Evgeny Maltsev Thank you, I have tried it, It works with fragments within the same fragmentpageradapter, but not working with fragments created in another fragmentpageradapter.

Comment: Perhaps you could register EventBus in the application class or some other common ancestor to make it accessible the way you need it.